# Setting counters for different subjects in a document

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters

I define different types of pictures (humans, animals, shapes, ...etc.) to be used in my document.

Is there a way to set counters for these different types, so that I can trace how many pictures there are for the different categories!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\arrowa
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\humana
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\humanb
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\housea
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\boata
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\boatb
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\birda
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\birdb
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\turtlea
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\candlea
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\candleb
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\horseb
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\doga
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\cata
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\def\rabbita
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
number of human figures: 6
number of dog figures: 4
number of candle figures: 2
number of horse figures: 8

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose to use an `expl3` property list (`l3prop`) to store the number of pictures in each category.

Note: `\nbPicsInCategoryExp` is a fully expandable “variant” of `\nbPicsInCategory`: the former is theoretically slower than the latter (with a large number of categories), but can be used in expansion-only contexts: inside `\numexpr`, `\dimexpr`, `\edef`, `siunitx`'s `\num` and `\SI` macros, plus many, many other places.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % only necessary if your LaTeX is older than 2020-10-01
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_hany_picture_counts_prop

% #1: macro name for the picture, without the initial backslash
% #2: category name
\cs_new_protected:Npn \hany_define_picture:nn #1#2
  {
    % Get current counter value for the category in \l_tmpa_tl, or 0 if no
    % picture has been put in this category yet.
    \prop_get:NnNF \g_hany_picture_counts_prop {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
      { \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { 0 } }
    % Increase the counter for this category.
    \prop_gput:Nnx \g_hany_picture_counts_prop {#2}
      { \int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl + 1 } }

    % Define the macro containing the picture
    \cs_new_protected:cpn {#1}
  }

% Same arguments as for \hany_define_picture:nn
\NewDocumentCommand \myDefinePicture { m m }
  {
    \hany_define_picture:nn {#1} {#2}
  }

% #1: category name
\NewDocumentCommand \nbPicsInCategory { m }
  {
    \prop_get:NnNF \g_hany_picture_counts_prop {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
      { \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { 0 } }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__hany_nb_pics_in_category:n #1
  { \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} { 0 } {#1} }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__hany_nb_pics_in_category:n { f }

% Expandable version of \nbPicsInCategory. This allows using the result in
% expansion-only contexts, which is an advantage over \nbPicsInCategory,
% however \nbPicsInCategoryExp is slower (which is only noticeable with a
% large enough number of categories!).
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \nbPicsInCategoryExp { m }
  {
    \__hany_nb_pics_in_category:f
      { \prop_item:Nn \g_hany_picture_counts_prop {#1} }
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \nbCategories { }
  {
    \prop_count:N \g_hany_picture_counts_prop
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__hany_count_picture:nn #1#2 { + #2 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \nbPictures { }
  {
    \int_eval:n
      {
        0
        \prop_map_tokens:Nn \g_hany_picture_counts_prop
          { \__hany_count_picture:nn }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myDefinePicture{arrowa}{arrows}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{humana}{humans}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{humanb}{humans}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{housea}{houses}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{boata}{boats}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{boatb}{boats}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{birda}{birds}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{birdb}{birds}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{turtlea}{turtles}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[green!20!brown] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=1cm, y radius=1.2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{candlea}{candles}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{candleb}{candles}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{doga}{dogs}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{dogb}{dogs}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\noindent
Number of categories: \nbCategories
\qquad \arrowa \qquad \turtlea\\
Number of pictures: \nbPictures

\noindent
Number of birds, dogs and turtles:
$\nbPicsInCategory{birds} + \nbPicsInCategory{dogs} + \nbPicsInCategory{turtles}
 = \the\numexpr \nbPicsInCategoryExp{birds} +
                \nbPicsInCategoryExp{dogs} +
                \nbPicsInCategoryExp{turtles} \relax$.

\medskip \noindent
Number of arrows: \nbPicsInCategory{arrows}\\
Number of human figures: \nbPicsInCategory{humans}\\
Number of bird figures: \nbPicsInCategory{birds}\\
Number of dog figures: \nbPicsInCategory{dogs}\\
Number of candle figures: \nbPicsInCategory{candles}\\
Number of house figures: \nbPicsInCategory{houses}\\
Number of turtle figures: \nbPicsInCategory{turtles}\\
Number of boat figures: \nbPicsInCategory{boats}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, I got an error message "! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \ExplSyntaxOn". Just one more request. How to get the total number of all categories? Thank you.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. The added `\usepackage{xparse}` may solve the compilation error you encountered; if it doesn't, it means your LaTeX is really too old. I've also added command `\nbCategories` which expands to the number of categories seen so far.

Comment: @– frougon Thank you for your reply. As you can see, there are 13 items, but number of categories shows only 8.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/L50Qu.png

Comment: Sorry, but you are confusing pictures (“items“) and categories. `humana` and `humanb` are both in the `humans` category, `boata` and `boatb` are both in the `boats` category, etc. In my example, there are 8 categories (you can count the lines of the second paragraph) and 13 pictures. I've added a macro `\nbPictures` that expands to the number of pictures that have been defined with `\myDefinePicture`. It expands to `13` in my example, after all pictures have been defined.

Comment: @– frougon Thank you very much for your solution, time, and concern.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it helped. I've added `\nbPicsInCategoryExp`, which is a fully expandable implementation of `\nbPicsInCategory` (see the sample use inside `\numexpr`).

Comment: @– frougon Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{doga}      % < -- one counter for each kind of figure
\def\doga
{%
\stepcounter{doga}%    % <-- add 1 to counter only when using the \doga command
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%


\begin{document}
number of dog figures: \thedoga\

\doga % you have to use at least once to increase counter

number of dog figures: \thedoga\

\doga % everytime you use, add 1 to counter

number of dog figures: \thedoga\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Just one request. How to get the total number of all figures. Thank you.

Comment: I used for each category "\stepcounter{xx} \stepcounter{all}" to generate 2 counters for each category. Is this correct! I wonder is it possible to generate the count at the beginning of the document instead of at the end!

Comment: @Hany, well, if you define a counter and step it inside every figure, no problem, it will store the total value.

Comment: @Hany, sorry, but I didn't follow what you mean by *at the beginning*.

Comment: @– Sigur I mean generating the counter at the beginning of the document, as if a TOC.

Comment: @Hany, ah, you mean to print the counter value before using it. I see.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the asked question, but a response to a comment. This should really be an answer to a separate question.

Numbers are known at end of document, but numbers can be printed at beginning of document if two runs are used.

With `tocloft` package, you can define a new list (say, `mynums`) and associated storage file (say, `.nol`). At end of document, when all numbers are known and final, write them to the `.nol` file with `\addtocontents{nol}{...}`.

Then you can print the list at document beginning with `\listofmynums`.
Requires two compilation runs.

For illustration, the example uses the expl3 answer by @frougon as base, but similar method applies to any answer:

[image: count summary]

I changed the print commands to the `\nbPicsInCategoryExp` version, so that the expanded value goes into the `.nol` file instead of the command name.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof{mynums}{nol}{Summary}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse} % only necessary if your LaTeX is older than 2020-10-01

\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_hany_picture_counts_prop

% #1: macro name for the picture, without the initial backslash
% #2: category name
\cs_new_protected:Npn \hany_define_picture:nn #1#2
  {
    % Get current counter value for the category in \l_tmpa_tl, or 0 if no
    % picture has been put in this category yet.
    \prop_get:NnNF \g_hany_picture_counts_prop {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
      { \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { 0 } }
    % Increase the counter for this category.
    \prop_gput:Nnx \g_hany_picture_counts_prop {#2}
      { \int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl + 1 } }

    % Define the macro containing the picture
    \cs_new_protected:cpn {#1}
  }

% Same arguments as for \hany_define_picture:nn
\NewDocumentCommand \myDefinePicture { m m }
  {
    \hany_define_picture:nn {#1} {#2}
  }

% #1: category name
\NewDocumentCommand \nbPicsInCategory { m }
  {
    \prop_get:NnNF \g_hany_picture_counts_prop {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
      { \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { 0 } }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__hany_nb_pics_in_category:n #1
  { \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} { 0 } {#1} }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__hany_nb_pics_in_category:n { f }

% Expandable version of \nbPicsInCategory. This allows using the result in
% expansion-only contexts, which is an advantage over \nbPicsInCategory,
% however \nbPicsInCategoryExp is slower (which is only noticeable with a
% large enough number of categories!).
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \nbPicsInCategoryExp { m }
  {
    \__hany_nb_pics_in_category:f
      { \prop_item:Nn \g_hany_picture_counts_prop {#1} }
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \nbCategories { }
  {
    \prop_count:N \g_hany_picture_counts_prop
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__hany_count_picture:nn #1#2 { + #2 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \nbPictures { }
  {
    \int_eval:n
      {
        0
        \prop_map_tokens:Nn \g_hany_picture_counts_prop
          { \__hany_count_picture:nn }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\listofmynums

Material in document \ldots

\myDefinePicture{arrowa}{arrows}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{humana}{humans}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{humanb}{humans}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{housea}{houses}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{boata}{boats}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{boatb}{boats}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{birda}{birds}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{birdb}{birds}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{turtlea}{turtles}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[green!20!brown] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=1cm, y radius=1.2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{candlea}{candles}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{candleb}{candles}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{doga}{dogs}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myDefinePicture{dogb}{dogs}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%Summary:
\addtocontents{nol}{Number of categories: \nbCategories\par}
\addtocontents{nol}{Number of pictures: \nbPictures\par}


\addtocontents{nol}{Number of birds, dogs and turtles:
$\nbPicsInCategoryExp{birds} + \nbPicsInCategoryExp{dogs} + \nbPicsInCategoryExp{turtles}
 = \the\numexpr \nbPicsInCategoryExp{birds} +
                \nbPicsInCategoryExp{dogs} +
                \nbPicsInCategoryExp{turtles} \relax$.\par
}

\addtocontents{nol}{%
Number of arrows: \nbPicsInCategoryExp{arrows}\par
Number of human figures: \nbPicsInCategoryExp{humans}\par
Number of bird figures: \nbPicsInCategoryExp{birds}\par
Number of dog figures: \nbPicsInCategoryExp{dogs}\par
Number of candle figures: \nbPicsInCategoryExp{candles}\par
Number of house figures: \nbPicsInCategoryExp{houses}\par
Number of turtle figures: \nbPicsInCategoryExp{turtles}\par
Number of boat figures: \nbPicsInCategoryExp{boats}\par
\smallskip
\hrule\par\bigskip}

\vdots 

\ldots End of document

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I will try it.